# Paypal IPN not sending recurring payment information

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm attempting to implement subscription payments using django-paypal standard by generating a "subscribe" button. I am able to receive the IPN post data however there is no information for recurring payments being returned. Apart form that the transaction is being registered on paypal. I am working in the sandbox environment.

The data I am sending is as follows:

```
dict = {
    "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "a3": "11.99",                      
    "p3": "1",                            
    "t3": "M",                         
    "src": "1",                        
    "sra": "0",        
    "no_note": "1",
    "no_shipping": "1",
    "rm": "1",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "lc": "US",
    "quantity": "1",
    "invoice": invoice_number,
    "item_name": "Item 1",
    'item_number': "1",
    "notify_url": notify_url_value,
    "return_url": return_url_value,
    "cancel_return": cancel_url_value,
    "custom": uid,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of issue I see in your dict. Fixing below **keys** values may resolve your issue.

- `P3` should be an integer, but you are passing it as a string
- `notify_url`, `return_url` and `cancel_return` should represent actual urls

  "notify_url": "http://www.example.com/your-ipn-location/"

  "return_url": "http://www.example.com/your-return-location/"

  "cancel_return": "http://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/"

Comment: They are actual urls I have just exchanged the values for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Oh I see. Did you try setting `P3` to integer?